Type is not assignable to type UnwrapRef
The below code shows an error on the line
tableItemsOptions.value.search = searchArray

Error:
Type 'Record<string, string | null>' is not assignable to type 'UnwrapRef<Record<keyof T, string | null>>'

My Code:
interface TableOptionsParsed<T extends Record<string, any>>
  extends Omit<TableItemsOptions, "sortBy" | "search"> {
  search?: Record<keyof T, string | null>; // Search by fields that exist in T
  orderBy?: Partial<Record<keyof T, "asc" | "desc">>; // Sorting as an object mapping fields to directions
  direction?: "asc" | "desc"; // Optional general direction if needed
}

const tableItemsOptions = ref<TableOptionsParsed<T>>({});

  // Watch for search changes and map them into the search options
  watch(search, searchValue => {
    console.log("watchsearv", searchValue);
    const searchArray: Record<string, string | null> = {};
    headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.multiSearch !== false && searchValue) {
        searchArray[header.value] = searchValue;
      }
    });
    console.log("watchsearv array", searchArray);
    tableItemsOptions.value.search = searchArray;
  });

I though the issue might be due to mismatch in the record itself where in typescript the key is 'keyof T' and in the watch it is 'string'
watch(search, searchValue => {
    console.log("watchsearv", searchValue);

    // Initialize searchArray as Partial to allow flexibility in setting keys
    const searchArray: Partial<Record<keyof T, string | null>> = {};

    headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.multiSearch !== false && searchValue) {
        searchArray[header.value as keyof T] = searchValue;
      }
    });

    console.log("watchsearv array", searchArray);

    // Assign the searchArray to tableItemsOptions.value.search
    // Cast back to the full Record<keyof T, string | null>
    tableItemsOptions.value.search = searchArray as Record<keyof T, string | null>;
  });

But I get the same error, how can i fix this?
UPDATE:
this is the full composable which should be a generic one to work with any v-data-table-server items type:
import { ref, Ref, watch } from "vue";
import { TableItemsOptions } from "@/types/TableItemsOptions";
import { useSearchableTable, Headers } from "./UseSearchableTable";

// Define a more generic version of TableOptionsParsed
interface TableOptionsParsed<T extends Record<string, any>>
  extends Omit<TableItemsOptions, "sortBy" | "search"> {
  search?: Record<keyof T, string | null>; // Search by fields that exist in T
  orderBy?: Record<keyof T, "asc" | "desc">; // Sorting as an object mapping fields to directions
  direction?: "asc" | "desc"; // Optional general direction if needed
}

export function useServerSearchableTable<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  originalItems: Ref<T[]>, // Generic array of items
  headers: Headers[] // Headers remain generic to any table structure
) {
  const {
    filteredItems,
    search,
    changeItemsToOriginal,
    filteredDataChange,
    onSearchValueChanged,
    multiSearchHeaders,
  } = useSearchableTable(originalItems, headers);

  const tableItemsOptions = ref<TableOptionsParsed<T>>({});

  // Watch for search changes and map them into the search options
  watch(search, searchValue => {
    console.log("watchsearv", searchValue);

    // Initialize searchArray as Partial to allow flexibility in setting keys
    const searchArray: Record<keyof T, string | null> = {};

    headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.multiSearch !== false && searchValue) {
        searchArray[header.value as keyof T] = searchValue;
      }
    });
    console.log("watchsearv array", searchArray);
    tableItemsOptions.value.search = searchArray;
  });

  const onAdvancedSearchChange = (val: Record<keyof T, string | null> | undefined = undefined) => {
    // If no value is provided, clear the search
    if (!val) {
      // tableItemsOptions.value.search = {} as Record<keyof T, string | null>;
      return;
    }

    // Convert search criteria into a generic record of key-value pairs
    const searchArray: Record<keyof T, string | null> = Object.entries(val)
      .filter(([_, value]) => value !== null && value !== "")
      .reduce((acc: Record<keyof T, string | null>, [key, value]) => {
        acc[key as keyof T] = value; // Accumulate key-value pairs
        return acc;
      }, {} as Record<keyof T, string | null>); // Use Partial for initialization
    console.log("advace array", searchArray);
    tableItemsOptions.value.search = searchArray as Record<keyof T, string | null>; // Cast to the expected type
  };

  // Load table items with pagination and sorting
  function loadItems({ itemsPerPage, page, sortBy }: TableItemsOptions) {
    tableItemsOptions.value = {
      ...tableItemsOptions.value,
      itemsPerPage,
      page,
  }

  return {
    filteredItems,
    search,
    changeItemsToOriginal,
    filteredDataChange,
    onSearchValueChanged,
    multiSearchHeaders,
    loadItems,
    tableItemsOptions,
    onAdvancedSearchChange,
  };
}


What is "T" in ref<TableOptionsParsed<T>> ?

T allows this interface to be generic over the structure of the items in the table. Instead of hardcoding the properties of the items. This composable in general should be a generic composable that any v-data-table-server can use without the need to duplicate code when items type changes

@EstusFlask I added the full composable code if that helps
